# Lightbox shows image at the bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I am using Lightbox in order to display images in bigger size in a website. Lately, I realized it is working in some pages (http://ipd2004.es/tornillos-para-protesis-anguladas-tpa) but it is not working in one specific page (http://ipd2004.es/producto/hexagono-externo-325). Neither this one nor any of the other product displayed in the left sidebar.

In this case, it enlarges the height of the page, and displays the image at the bottom of it, without creating any of the common popup window to display the image and keeping the focus at the top of the page, so at the eyes of the user, the image is not expanded. Curious is, if I keep clicking, it keeps enlarging the page height, and the image stays at the bottom of it.

I checked and I am using the same JS calls in both pages, the one working and the one not. So what am I doing wrong?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the browser console? The page where it is not working, an error is displayed. Check below image

[image]

Comment: There was an error with the URL in this page, and lightbox.css was not read. Thank you! Solved.